# Properly Passing Parameters to a function

Tags: function, powershell, variables

guys! Today in my adventures in coding I am trying to create a powershell script that relies on user input to set Variables.  A primary goal of this script is to be able to input a computer name and a network location and remote delete a file on the specified computer on the domain. Note that this does work with getting the computer name from a text. However, I want to avoid having to create/edit the .txt file manually editing the location in the function and have the variables pulled from the host input.

Question 1.) Is that something possible to even do?
Question 2.) Can someone look at my code and provide suggestions to properly pass parameters to a function?

```
param (
[string] $Computer = $(Read-Host "Copy Paste Computer name"),
[string] $Location = $(Read-Host "Copy Paste Malicious folder/file location starting with Profile 
name")
)

function delete-remotefile {
PROCESS {
            $file = "\\$_\c$\$Location"    
            if (test-path $file)
            {
            echo "$_ file exists"
            Remove-Item $file -force -recurse
            echo "$_ file deleted"
            }
            $file = "\\$_\c$\$Location"          
            if (test-path $file)
            {
            echo "$_ file exists"
            Remove-Item $file -force -recurse
            echo "$_ file deleted"
            }
        }
}

Get-Content $Location | delete-remotefile
```

Comment: Yes, put the param block in your function. Then change your `$_` var to the corresponding variable. You're providing pipeline input so it needs to be specified as well as a parameter attribute, `valuefrompipeline=$true` although `$true` isn't necessary.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.

Comment: Comment back if you are having trouble, once I get on my computer I'll post an example.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I am having trouble. I understand your suggestion, but when I edit the code, I am not able to format it properly. I would greatly appreciate an example.

Comment: Okay, to clarify some things. Can you rephrase what you want done? You want to be able to pass the computer from the pipeline to your function?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Actually, I was able to implement your suggestion. It works as I needed it to. Thank you again!!!!!!!

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I left the Param block as is, Edited the "$_" to reflect "$Computer" and removed the pipe at the bottom and just called the function. When I launch the .ps1, I am prompted for input and if the file exists, it gets zapped.